# cannot create new directories

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, ntfs, disk-usage

I cannot create new directories with specific names on a partition.
It happend on Ununtu 20.10, I updated to 21.04 and it still happen.
Here is the error I receive:

```
l*@l*-desktop:/media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E/Movies$ mkdir thesting
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘thesting’: Input/output error
l*@l*-desktop:/media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E/Movies$ mkdir the
l*@l*-desktop:/media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E/Movies$ mkdir 'The Sting'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘The Sting’: Input/output error
```

Tried to mount the partition as 'rw', it still happens:

```
l*@l*-desktop:/media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E/Movies$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 -o rw,remount 
[sudo] password for *: 
l*@l*-desktop:/media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E/Movies$ mkdir thesting
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘thesting’: Input/output error
```

Here are the permissions for this directory:

```
l*@l*-desktop:/media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E$ ls -l| grep Movies
drwxrwxrwx 1 luc luc 36864 mai  9 15:26 Movies
```

Outside this directory this problem do not happen:

```
l*@l*-desktop:/media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E$ mkdir 'The Sting'
l*@l*-desktop:/media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E$ mkdir thesting the
l*@l*-desktop:/media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E$ ls -l 'The Sting' thesting the
the:
total 0

thesting:
total 0

'The Sting':
total 0
```

Any idea what can be the cause and how I can fix it without deleting and recreating the directory ?

Thank you!

Yes, it's NTFS. I see there is not too much space left on this partition:

```
l*@lu*-desktop:/media/lucian/2CC6D638C6D6024E/Movies$ df -Th 
Filesystem Type Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda2      fuseblk  440G  432G  8,5G  99% /media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E
```

I want to find out the root cause of the problem first, don't want to move the files yet.

Also, I don't know where these 432 GB come from. All the sda2 partition content has 381 GB. And a few big directories form Movies dissapeared unexpectedly yesterday.

I found a lot of hidden files inside 'Movies': .22f2fdf35de63b5c35b996e6440b91ae88e6daa8.parts .25d1bb64e8e1d811c598a8b906631b3dbaf2730a.parts .28187e4b8af4ba76bbcf897c870bc4b57ebd08e1.parts .28b13a5892d424fb57b31a3eeefad503ca484b23.parts .2a924a38dd41201b0428b62dd9dd12e4dbf9ef6c.parts .2bc46380d7f5f2db5e9cf51f6c3de66aab3b941e.parts .2ca1f0a32640fac53c81292964f117af858adb1b.parts .3373514dcdb91d5125841d12b69abfb4d6d21ca4.parts .376d35c4ca48268c64f889065150e881509d0de3.parts .3916ea102d54f6ca23a1af69387c620468c4a25e.parts ...

I removed them, but only ~100MB has been freed.

Comment: This is probably an NTFS filesystem. Check with `df -T .`. Can you try by creating a new directory parallel to `Movies` (say `Movies2`) and move your files there?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Yes, it's NTFS. I see there is not too much space left on this partition:                                                                                                                     l*@lu*-desktop:/media/lucian/2CC6D638C6D6024E/Movies$ df -Th
Filesystem     Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      fuseblk  440G  432G  8,4G  99% /media/l@/2CC6D638C6D6024E                          I want to find out the root cause of the problem first, don't want to move the files yet.

Comment: Also, I don't know where these 432 GB come from. All the sda2 partition content has 381 GB. And a few big directories form Movies dissapeared unexpectedly yesterday.

Comment: I found a lot of hidden files inside 'Movies': .22f2fdf35de63b5c35b996e6440b91ae88e6daa8.parts
 .25d1bb64e8e1d811c598a8b906631b3dbaf2730a.parts
 .28187e4b8af4ba76bbcf897c870bc4b57ebd08e1.parts
 .28b13a5892d424fb57b31a3eeefad503ca484b23.parts
 .2a924a38dd41201b0428b62dd9dd12e4dbf9ef6c.parts
 .2bc46380d7f5f2db5e9cf51f6c3de66aab3b941e.parts
 .2ca1f0a32640fac53c81292964f117af858adb1b.parts
 .3373514dcdb91d5125841d12b69abfb4d6d21ca4.parts
 .376d35c4ca48268c64f889065150e881509d0de3.parts
 .3916ea102d54f6ca23a1af69387c620468c4a25e.parts
...

Comment: Hi , these parts could be unfinished downloaded "stuff". So, if all your files are complete, you may be safe deleting these parts files. That will help you win some space.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Those filenames look like an encrypted filesystem's underlying, encrypted files. DON'T mess with them, don't use this directory at all! `mount` the partition

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added all the answers in the description.